# Extending the custom class in laravel 4

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4

I have a model class called "CustomItem.php" inside models folder

```
class CustomItem extends Neoquent {
   ...
}
```

and im not using namespaces in CustomItem.php. I have Neoquent.php inside same folder with the code

```
class Neoquent extends Eloquent {
   ...
}
```

i have autoloaded the class file folder in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models"
        ]
    },
```

and i have registered the additional classes in global.php

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models'
));
```

but i get the following error

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)
Class 'Neoquent' not found

Comment: Did you re-run `install`? From the composer doc: "After adding the autoload field, you have to re-run install to re-generate the vendor/autoload.php file."

Comment: Yes i did it but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer dump-autoload` - as mentioned above the autoload.php needs to be recreated

Comment: I ran the command composer dump-autoload and composer install but still no luck :(